# Google Sheets limit on function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, limit

I have formula that I've been using for a while however the formula doesn't work properly anymore.
This is the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(FILTER(C3:HG3,(C2:HG2="keyword")*(C3:HG3<>"")),1,COUNTIFS(C2:HG2,"keyword",C3:HG3,"<>")))
```

From time to time I expend the columns and populate them with data.
I started using the formula somewhere from column FX now to column HG and I would like to expend it to column HJ but the formula doesn't work anymore. Is there a limit on calculations on formula's in Google sheets?

Comment: As said by @player0 try to share a copy of your sheet deleting all personal information. On doing so please try to give an example of the desired output that you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(FILTER(C3:HJ3, (C2:HJ2="keyword")*(C3:HJ3<>"")), 1, 
 COUNTIFS(C2:HJ2, "keyword", C3:HJ3, "<>")))
```

Comment: thnx player0, didn't work unfortunately, however no errors just an empty cell

Comment: @Tom can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: excuse me for the delay, i tried to recreate the problem on a blank sheet and there the formula works fine...let me investigate this